# Using window.location and return confirm together

Tags: javascript

I have this button that will send a user to a page but first ask the user to confirm, but it's not working correctly, how can I fix it? Thanks

`<input class="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>';return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your post?');" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a new function

```
void redirect(url) {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your post?')) {
    window.location.href=url;
  }
  return false;
}
```

then from your `onclick`

```
onclick="redirect('<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>');"
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
<input class="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your post?')) window.location.href='http://www.google.com';" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn the commands around. You are leaving the current page, *then* doing the confirm. That can't work.

```
if (confirm(...))  window.location.href='....'
```

Comment: The redirect **isn't** working though when I click the Ok button?

Comment: No error it just doesn't do the redirect :/ I've used a function above instead. Thanks for the help though!